# MongoDB (mongoose): Cast to [string] failed for value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

There's something wrong happens when I try to update a document in DB.

Here is Schema:

```
const prodSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  description: {
    type: [String]
  },
})
```

Then I get some product from elsewhere:

```
const some_product = axios.get(blah blah)
```

And update mu document.
Note that I set up a condition for a 'description': if it has a null value, it is updated - else it remains the same:

```
const newProduct = {
$set: {
    name: some_product.name,
    description: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [null, '$description']
              },
              then: [some_product.description],
              else: '$description'
            }
    }
}
```

}

Go update (I use mongoose):
Product.updateOne({name: some_product.name}, newProduct, {some params})

And I see this:

> Cast to [string] failed for value
> "[{"$cond":{"if":{"$eq":[null,"$description"]},"then":["Here is some
> new description of the prosuct"],"else":"$description"}}]" at path
> "description"

I think the point is that the type of description in the schema is array of strings, and 'description' field in the requested 'some_product' is just a string. May be this is the issue.

But how do I solve it?
Many thanks.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi I'm sorry but I didn't get what you mean(

Answer (score 0):

```
var description = []
description.push(some_product.description)
const newProduct = [{
$set: {
    name: some_product.name,
    description: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [null, '$description']
              },
              then: description,
              else: '$description'
            }
    }
}
}]
```

put update operation in `[]` use update pipeline
for example
`model.update({},[{$set: ...}])`

Comment: Nope, still the same.
My theory:
the error message says: '...value "[{"$cond":{"if":{"$eq":[null,"$description"]},"then":["Here is some new description of the prosuct"],"else":"$description"}}]"'

It tries to apply this whole value '[{"$cond"...' to the description filed. 

If in the schema I change [String] to Object, I have another error: "error: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'description.0.$cond' is not valid for storage."

Comment: Now it says "error: BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'"
Google says nothing clear. Looks like it doesn't like [array] literal

Comment: could you provide the whole code of update ?